# Multiple databases in RoR: Issue with migration applied to the wrong database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations, ruby-on-rails-6, multiple-databases

I want to add a secondary database to my RoR project, so I followed this: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html

So now I have two databases: `jobtitleio` & `profiles`

My issue is that when I run: `rails db:migrate:profiles`, the migration is applied to the other database (the primary one). => in this example, I want to add a table, and the table is added to the `jobtitleio` database.

Here is my `database.yml`:

```
development:
  jobtitleio:
    <<: *default
    database: jobtitleio_development
  profiles:
    <<: *default
    database: profiles_development
    migrations_paths: db/profiles/migrate
```

I ran this to create the migration: 
`rails g migration CreateUsers url:text external_id:integer --database profiles`
which created the migration file in the right folder (`db/profiles/migrate`).

So this is where I'm at, my migration is created in the right folder, and is ran to be applied to the profiles database (using `rails db:migrate:profiles`). So why is it applied to the other database ?

Thanks for your help !